# Replace lots of old links on a site with new links? (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system, greasemonkey

We are currently migrating articles from our old CMS to our new CMS. The problem is that the links in the old articles are hard-coded and are referencing to the old sites.

We migrators have no access to the database, so all articles and all links have to be changed manually.
I have the old sitemap and the new sitemap and would like to write a Greasemonkey/jQuery-script to click a button and the script would change all old-cms-links to the new-cms-links.

What would be the best/most elegant solution in this case? Working with arrays? There are 500+ sites/articles...

What would you suggest keeping in mind, that only client-side scripts are allowed?

Currently I have this little snippet, that marks all old links with a !

```
$("#links").click(function() 
{
    $('a[href*="pattern-of-old-cms"]')
        .append('<span class="attention" style="font-size: 25px; color:red;">!</span>');
});
```

Comment: Can't you use an `.htaccess` in your case ? It would be the best solution, using the `[R=301]` tag.

Comment: nope, only client-side access :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't run 500+ `.attr()` statements!  Use a more efficient way of processing the pages.

Create two files like this:

old_URLs.js:

```
var oldUrlArray = [
    "Old address 1",
    "Old address 2",
    "Old address 3",
    // etc., etc.
]
```

new_URLs.js:

```
var newUrlArray = [
    "New address 1",
    "New address 2",
    "New address 3",
    // etc., etc.
]
```

and place them in the same folder as your gm`.user.js` file.

Then your script becomes:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Mass link replacer remapper
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  old_URLs.js
// @require  new_URLs.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var oldLinks = $('a[href*="pattern-of-old-cms"]');

while (oldLinks.length) {
    var firstHref = oldLinks[0].href;
    var hrefIndex = oldUrlArray.indexOf (firstHref);

    if (hrefIndex >= 0) {
        var toReplace   = oldLinks.filter ("[href='" + firstHref + "']");
        toReplace.attr ("href", newUrlArray[hrefIndex]);

        oldLinks = oldLinks.not (toReplace);
    }
    else {
        alert ("I don't know how to map the link: " + firstHref);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! I think this will work fine, I already thought about solving this task with arrays but needed a hint :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href='http://www.google.com/']").attr('href', 'http://www.live.com/');
```

one solution would be to do this for all the links

Comment: sure, but with 500 different links?

Comment: hardly, the old links are like this /index.php?id=181 and the new one's have friendly urls like /about-us
Looks like your jquery solution is the only one...

Comment: Load a javascript which has mapping for old url to new url in a map.

Then replace the paths accordingly using the approach suggested here

Comment: make and excel spreadsheet with: 
Column A: $("a[href=' 
Column B: old link 
Column C: ']").attr('href', ' 
Column D: New link
Column E: '); 


Copy all the contents in notepad and replace tabs with nothing. done

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use your excel tip with the array solution from Brock